# Laravel Eloquent withCount "Call to a member function getQuery() on null"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Feed Model**

```
class Feed extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
        'userId',
        'title',
    ];
    public function likes()
    {
        $this->hasMany(FeedLike::class, 'feedId', 'id');
    }
}

class FeedLike extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'feedId',
        'userId',
    ];

}

**Controller**

Feed::withCount('likes')->get();
```

return error message "Call to a member function getQuery() on null".

I've already check Laravel documentation for Syntax & check stack Overflow related Questions too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just forget to add `return` in `like` method, it should be:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FeedLike::class, 'feedId', 'id');
}
```